# Errors while submitting windows phone app to the store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

i was trying to submit my app to the Windows Phone Store, but i got these errors:

[image]
[image]

In Visual Studio 2013, i compiled the solution as release and not as debug. One of those Microsoft's links (the first error) suggests to add a flag to the linker, but i didn't manage to do that.

Also, the second one regards a bunch of unsupported APIs that i didn't even include in my project. Did someone face the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check thirdparty libraries or you code for some API which not allowed for Windows Phone 8.1 Store Apps

For example, I added Flurry WP8.0 SDK in my WP8.1 Store App and I have the same problems. After that I removed Flurry and Store accepted my App

Comment: I didn't use any particular API in my app, so i think that it's not caused by this reason.

Comment: what about webservices.dll? WsFreeChanel, WSCreateListener etc

Comment: Actually i did use HTMLAgilityPack, but i didn't find it in the error list.

Comment: Try replace your HtmlAgility pack libraries to PCL version

Comment: I'll try that, are the classes/methods still the same?

Comment: I don't know. Or you can try update current libraries

Comment: The problem persists even with the PCL version.

Comment: Are you use some cpp libraries?

Comment: Nope, i only used agility pack and microsoft advertising.

Comment: Maybe you publish your app in Debug Mode?
I have no idea

Comment: No, i double checked it several times, i replaced every "debug" with "release".